# JS Exercise on Codecademy not working - accessing object data with bracket notation

Tags: javascript, oop, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying this problem. [Edited]

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wants you to set `aProperty` to the property name, and then use that with the variable `james` to get the value.

```
var james = {
    job: "programmer",
    married: false
};

// set to the first property name of "james"
var aProperty = 'job';

// print the value of the first property of "james" 
// using the variable "aProperty"
console.log(james[aProperty])
```

Comment: That's the answer... thank you. I must say, that is an incredibly... incredibly stupid way of doing that . And the explanation couldn't have been less clear, in my opinion.

Comment: I think the goal is to ease you into it. But yes, sometimes the instructions can be less than clear on CA.

Comment: @Mazzone: would you consider accepting this answer? To do so, click the tick mark to the left. This is how we mark questions as resolved here.